# Simulator for NEMA17 (stepper motor) and A4988 (stepper motor driver) along with Arduino

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, simulation, simulator, stepper-driver

I want to simulate an Arduino MEGA (or UNO) controlling a NEMA17 (stepper motor) using A4988 (stepper motor driver). I couldn't find the stepper motor and driver on TinkerCAD. Can this be done in Proteus? Or is there any other workaround possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in Proteus. You can simulate a stepper motor there, but only to see the motion, it is not possible to simulate the speed, inertia, and mechanical response.